# How to auto generate Download Page for music folders?

Tags: sql, mobile, content-management-system, portal

Scenario :I am trying to build a Mobile Entertainment Portal. It will enable users to download Music & Movies to their Cell Phones...

Problem Exp : Suppose I upload 100 folders of Songs, each folder is for one Album. I want a way to generate a page with all the folders name (Album Name) in it. If user click on the page, they should be taken to a page where they get list of all songs in the album. Clicking on any song name will let them download it.

Can it be done anyway or will I have to manually design each of the 3 pages for each album. If I do that, its time consuming and also will be difficult to change anything like footer, header...

Also I want to know if I can monitor Realtime Download Statistics.

Comment: Yes, all this can be done very easily. No, you don't have to manually create pages for each album. You just have to learn database programming.

Comment: I have some knowledge of MySQL+PHP. But m not sure the way I need to take. It   would be really helpfull if you please explain a bit outhere...

Comment: See egrunin's answer. That's really the best you are going to get. This isn't so much a site for basic programming tutorials. Once you get a handle on the basics and have some specific code questions, come back.

Answer (score 1):

1. You create a database
2. You create one or more template pages, each taking a relevant ID, such as AlbumID (which you might be calling FolderID) as a URL parameter
3. At runtime, the page logic fetches the data (by AlbumID) and lays it out nicely for the user.

This sort of thing is covered in every entry-level database programming text. A quick search turned up [this](http://devzone.zend.com/6/php-101-php-for-the-absolute-beginner/) and [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1592004946).